# Synchronize project source code between 2 team servers

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I work on a project stored on 2 team servers : a local team server where several coders are working, and a codeplex project where I send the updates.

I have on my computers 2 copies of the source code, and I copy the modification from one to the other.

What is the best way to synchronize the source code between the two servers ? (with only one copy of the source code, or a tool who can compare the two versions and automatically sends update to codeplex)

Comment: Almost 5 years later, I now use Git when working on open source projects, it allows source control to be saved on several servers